# Babel not compiling For - of loop

Tags: babeljs

I installed *babel-preset-0* and included it in the `.babelrc` file, I also installed the `transform-runtime`, See my files below, But ***For of*** loop code is throwing error while compiling

code

```js
var mySet = new Set();

mySet.add(1);
mySet.add(5);
mySet.add("some text");

var myArr = [v for (v of mySet)];// throws error
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```js
loaders: [
                { test: path.join(__dirname, 'es6'),
                  loader: 'babel-loader' ,
                   // Options to configure babel with
                  query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                        plugins: [
                          'transform-runtime',                         
                          'transform-decorators-legacy',
                        ],
                  },
                  exclude: [
                              path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                            ]
              },
```

**.babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```